# What is the Python API for moving a collection?

Tags: python, collections

I created a Python like this

`bpy.ops.object.move_to_collection(collection_index=2, new_collection_name="Background")`

But this code must have a collection called "Background" in the scene from the beginning

I want this.

1. If there was no collection called "Background", we would create one with Python and move the selected object
2. If the "Background" collection exists, just move it instead of creating a new one

And I'd like to go from ViewPort to Hide
I created this code, but I don't know how to specify the "Background"

`bpy.context.scene.hide_viewport = True`

Digression

With just these two lines, I was able to create Empty if it wasn't there and select it if it was there.

```
bpy.ops.object.select_pattern(pattern="Empty")
bpy.ops.object.constraint_add_with_targets(type='TRACK_TO')
```

=====Edit=====

I was putting up the wrong code.
`bpy.context.scene.exclude = True`

When I modified it in this way, I get an error
`bg_col.hide_exclude = True`

Comment: Please ask only one question per post to make Q&A useful to others too. Please read: https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Oh, sorry...
I'll be more careful next time.
Forgive me for just asking this question for a moment...

Comment: After trying to code the process, I accidentally found out there is a bunch of condition that should be handle correctly. The process is not that easy when coder is not familiar with the `bpy` structure. Then this question need to split in several question to make it more general (or module? Atomic question?) to help other **reuse** this Q&A.

Answer (score 1):

```py
import bpy

C = bpy.context
D = bpy.data
S = D.scenes["Scene"]

if not D.collections.get("Background"): #Get collection by name in data, and check if None
    bg_col = D.collections.new("Background") # Create a new one if not found
    S.collection.children.link(bg_col)
    # Add it to your Scene unless you don't need to see it in your scene
else:
    bg_col = D.collections.get("Background")

bg_col.hide_viewport = True #This is not the eye icon but the monitor icon hidden
```

Comment: Can error if background collection is not part of the scene in context.

Comment: Then the process will be done silently. Not `Error` but an intentional if Background collection is in other scene....I guess? Not sure if there might be an real `Error` when dealing with collection not in current scene

Comment: I'm sorry! I wrote the wrong code in my questionnaire.
I've edited the question.

Comment: You can save 2 lines with `bg_col = D.collections.get("Background")` then `if bg_col is None:` etc. and you don't need the `else:`